# Neo4j relationship line design

Tags: neo4j, relationship

I am looking for some pointers/help to customize the relationship line between the nodes.
I have two nodes, User and Account. In my data set, there are multiple records with same User-Account combination. Currently when i generate the graph, there are multiple lines traversing from user node to Account node. 
Now my requirement is to have a one single line between user and account node, but the thickness of the line has to vary depending on the number of user-account combination available in the data set.

To make it clear, assume Userid - 1234 .. accountid - 9999 .. there are 50 records in the data set, with the same combination. In the graph, relationship line between userid:1234 and accountId:9999 nodes has to thicker, when compared to another set of userId:accountId combination which has only 5 records in the data set.

Is it possible to have this kind of relationship graph. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about making your own custom version of the Neo4J browser console or what? Relationships are a type in Neo4J. They don't have a "thickness".

Comment: What I meant is.. instead of having multiple lines going from one node to another, but just one single line - but width of the line dependent on the count of records.

Comment: I understand exactly what you're talking about, but you keep describing a graph (underlying dataset) and then talking about what to do with its visualization. We need to know the specs about how your visualization will work. Is this on the web? Native app? What?

Comment: Oops.. I messed up the question. I started using neo4j just 1 week back, so still getting accustomed to keywords. My question was regarding the visualization of the graph. Not directly related to neo4j.

Comment: I was able to generate the visualization using Rneo4j.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about visualization of the graph and it's not related to Neo4j (which is data store).

Yes it's possible to do that. Please tell us more about your goals.

Here is great guide about visualization - [Graph Visualization for Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/)

---

If you are talking about the Neo4j Browser that it's not possible or at least not without lots of hacks. But source code is available - https://github.com/oskarhane/neo4j/tree/master/community/browser

Comment: my Goal is to generate a graph where the nodes will get connected just by one line and width of this line will be dependent on the number of records available in dataset. This is my business requirement. which visualization tool is the best for this? Linkurious and tom Sawyer are not free.  I am looking for an open source tool. I started learning graph DB 1 week back, so I am not sure whether I am missing something here.

Comment: I was able to generate the visualization using Rneo4j.